# device telemetry page is at 1970

Tags: thingsboard

I have a data converter that generates the following output

```
[{
    "deviceName": "meter 34936959",
    "groupName": "All",
    "ts": 1579788289,
    "values": {
        "counter": 2686
    }
}]
```

timestamp is `1579788289`, which is `Thursday, 23 January 2020 14:04:49`
but in the device page, latest telemetry is `"1970-01-19 08:49:48"`

can you please help me to understand what is wrong with the structure?

[image: device telemetry page-screenshot]

Thank you

Comment: It would be useful for answerers if you could explain how you are generating this JSON and where you are sending it. For example, a link to the telemetry API you are using. In this case, it is clear what the problem is regardless, but a bit of context is handy (and will help other people with the same problem find the answer).

Answer (score 1):

It is expecting a timestamp in milliseconds, but you are supplying a timestamp in seconds.

- 1579788289 seconds since 1970 is "2020-01-23 14:04:49"
- 1579788289 milliseconds since 1970 is "1970-01-19 08:49:48"

There is an example of this in the [ThingsBoard documentation](https://thingsboard.io/docs/reference/http-api/#telemetry-upload-api):

> In the example above, we assume that “1451649600512” is a unix
>   timestamp with milliseconds precision.

If you can't get the millisecond timestamp, try multiplying your timestamp by 1000 before sending it. With your example, that would be:

```
[{
    "deviceName": "meter 34936959",
    "groupName": "All",
    "ts": 1579788289000,
    "values": {
        "counter": 2686
    }
}]
```

Comment: Thank you!!

I was expected to see this information also here:

https://thingsboard.io/docs/user-guide/integrations/#data-converters